# Add a gradient background line to the circle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a block on the page where there is a background line, on the line itself there is a circle that scrolls along with the main scroll

The question is, how can you make it so that, along with the circle, another line of the same color as the circle scrolls along the line, and it all would look something like this:

[image]

I tried adding styles to before, but it didn't work out what I expected

```
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 3px;
height: 40vh;
background: #4f8eff;
box-shadow: inset 0 20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e, inset 0 -20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e;
z-index: 2;
```

Everything should be like in the picture that I threw off, the circle should be white inside, and the blue color should completely overlap the yellow when we scrolled to the very top, and the same from the bottom. And in the center of the block, let's say the blue color should be both above the circle and below, while maintaining the gradient

In my example, almost the same as I want, but not to the end, I want that when the blue line reaches the end of the block, or to the beginning of the block, then the blue color completely overlaps the yellow. And now it turns out that when the circle is at the maximum position in the top, then yellow colors remain on top

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const cases = document.querySelectorAll(".case");

circle.style.transition = ""

const handleScroll = () => {
  const {
    height: blockHeight
  } = document.querySelector(".block2").getBoundingClientRect()

  const maxTop = cases[cases.length - 1].offsetTop + cases[cases.length - 1].offsetHeight - 200
  const minTop = cases[0].offsetTop

  let {
    height: startTop
  } = cases[0].getBoundingClientRect()

  const scrollDist = Math.min(maxTop, Math.max(startTop / 2 + window.scrollY, minTop))

  circle.style.top = `${scrollDist}px`
  circle.style.backgroundSize = `17px ${blockHeight}px`
  circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-scrollDist}px`
}

const handleWindowSizeAndScroll = () => {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  window.removeEventListener("resize", handleScroll)
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleScroll)
}

handleScroll()
handleWindowSizeAndScroll()
window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeAndScroll)
```

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block3 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block2,
.block2 .circle {
  background: linear-gradient(214deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 0%, #f5e550 10%, #f5e550 90%, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 100%) center/3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
}

.block2 .circle {
  background: #4f8eff;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block2 .circle,
.block2 .circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.block2 .circle::before {
  content: "";
  inset: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.block2 .circle::before {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3px;
  height: 40vh;
  background: #4f8eff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e, inset 0 -20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: Your sample code produces almost exactly what you seem to be asking for. The only difference is that the color of the circle doesn't quite match the color of the line where they overlap (the line is green but the circle is blue). Is that the problem? Do you want the line to be blue where it overlaps the circle?

Comment: @kmoser 
everything should be like in the picture that I threw off, the circle should be white inside, and the blue color should completely overlap the yellow when we scrolled to the very top, and the same from the bottom. And in the center of the block, let's say the blue color should be both above the circle and below, while maintaining the gradient

Comment: Your sample code produces almost exactly what you seem to be asking for. The only difference is that the color of the circle doesn't quite match the color of the line where they overlap

Comment: @MobinSalehi In my example, almost the same as I want, but not to the end, I want that when the blue line reaches the end of the block, or to the beginning of the block, then the blue color completely overlaps the yellow. And now it turns out that when the circle is at the maximum position in the top or bot, then yellow colors remain on top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660526/stop-scrolling-when-the-element-reaches-the-end-of-the-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close to what you want to achieve:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const cases = document.querySelectorAll(".case");

circle.style.transition = ""

const handleScroll = () => {
  const {
    height: blockHeight
  } = document.querySelector(".block2").getBoundingClientRect()

  const maxTop = cases[cases.length - 1].offsetTop + cases[cases.length - 1].offsetHeight - 200
  const minTop = cases[0].offsetTop

  let {
    height: startTop
  } = cases[0].getBoundingClientRect()

  const scrollDist = Math.min(maxTop, Math.max(startTop / 2 + window.scrollY, minTop))

  circle.style.top = `${scrollDist}px`
  circle.style.backgroundSize = `17px ${blockHeight}px`
  circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-scrollDist}px`
}

const handleWindowSizeAndScroll = () => {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  window.removeEventListener("resize", handleScroll)
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleScroll)
}

handleScroll()
handleWindowSizeAndScroll()
window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeAndScroll)
```

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block3 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block2 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 0%, #f5e550 140px, #f5e550 calc(100% - 140px), rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 100%) center/3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
}

.block2 .circle {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block2 .circle,
.block2 .circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.block2 .circle .gradient-container::before {
  content: "";
  inset: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  background: #4f8eff;
  width: 27px;
  height: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 32%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px #4f8eff;
}

.block2 .circle .gradient-container {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3px;
  height: 40vh;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block2 .circle::after {
content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 2px);
    z-index: 5;
    border: 4px solid #4f8eff;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="gradient-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your custom scrollbar. Note that you need to add additional event listeners if you want to be able to grab the thumb and scroll. Try scrolling with mouse-wheel to see the effect.

```js
const scrollBarEl = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll')[0];
const scrollEl = document.getElementsByClassName('outer-container')[0];
scrollEl.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  const scrollSpan = scrollEl.scrollHeight - scrollEl.clientHeight;
  if (scrollSpan !== 0)
    scrollBarEl.style.setProperty('--scroll', `${scrollEl.scrollTop / scrollSpan * 100}%`)
})
```

```css
.outer-container {
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  min-height: 400vh;
}

.scroll {
  --scroll: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff00, #ff0, #00f var(--scroll), #ff0, #ff00);
}

.thumb {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--scroll) - 6px);
  left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-container'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='scroll'>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not quite understand how I can make it look like my design

Answer (score 1):

As per your replies to comments, I believe that you want to scroll the circle along with the sections. Please check the solution in full screen

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const cases = document.querySelectorAll(".case");
const text1 = document.querySelector(".text1");
const block3 = document.querySelector(".block3");

const handleScroll = () => {
  const {
    height: blockHeight
  } = document.querySelector(".block2").getBoundingClientRect();

  const maxTop = cases[cases.length - 1].offsetTop + cases[cases.length - 1].offsetHeight - 200;
  const minTop = cases[0].offsetTop;
  const block3Top = block3.offsetTop - 700;

  let {
    height: startTop
  } = cases[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  let scrollDist = Math.min(maxTop, Math.max(startTop / 2 + window.scrollY, minTop));

  if (scrollDist <= minTop || scrollDist >= maxTop || scrollDist >= block3Top) {
    scrollDist = scrollDist <= minTop ? minTop : (scrollDist >= block3Top ? block3Top : maxTop);
    circle.style.backgroundSize = `17px 100%`;
    circle.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    circle.style.backgroundSize = `17px ${blockHeight}px`;
    if (scrollDist >= 250) {
      circle.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      circle.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  circle.style.top = `${scrollDist}px`;
  circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-scrollDist}px`;
};

const handleWindowSizeAndScroll = () => {
  handleScroll();
};

handleScroll();
handleWindowSizeAndScroll();
window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeAndScroll);
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block3 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block2,
.block2 .circle {
  background: linear-gradient(214deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 0%, #f5e550 10%, #f5e550 90%, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 100%) center/3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
}

.block2 .circle {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid #4f8eff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  transition: visibility 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

.block2 .circle::before,
.block2 .circle::after {
  content: "";
  inset: 3px;
}

.block2 .circle::after {
  left: 50%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #4f8eff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 50vh 25vh -25vh #4f8eff, inset 0 -50vh 25vh -25vh #4f8eff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block2 .circle::before {
  left: 50%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #4f8eff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 50vh 25vh -25vh #4f8eff, inset 0 -50vh 25vh -25vh #4f8eff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}

.text1 .circle.active,
.text1 .circle.active::before,
.text1 .circle.active::after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.circle,
.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.circle.active,
.circle.active::before,
.circle.active::after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.block3 .circle,
.block3 .circle::before,
.block3 .circle::after {
  transition: visibility 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

.block3 .circle,
.block3 .circle::before,
.block3 .circle::after {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="case">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
          <div class="col-2"></div>
          <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="case">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
          <div class="col-2"></div>
          <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="case">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 text text3">Text 3</div>
          <div class="col-2"></div>
          <div class="col-5 text text3">Text 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is almost what I need, only I need to keep a gradient between the intersection of colors. And when the blue color has reached the very top or the very bottom of the block, it must absorb all the yellow

Comment: And in your example, if you add blocks below and above this, then the scroll will go through them too

Comment: @Hector Please check the updated answer. Now scroll will not enter above and below block. It will start and end with transition

Comment: Only it is possible to make it so that it does not hide, but simply stops when the block ends?

Comment: @Hector What do you mean by stop? You mentioned when the blue colour has reached the very top or the very bottom of the block, it must absorb all the yellow. So when the scroll reaches to certain block, the circle and it's following line will `ease-out`. when you scroll back it `ease-in`. If the solution is the desired output, please accept the answer

Comment: Yes, when the blue line reaches the end it should just take the yellow spot and the circle itself should stop and not disappear. Perhaps I made a mistake and incorrectly conveyed information to you, sorry for misleading you